# Slightly more complex jQuery Travsersing problem

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a page that displays search results and has a DOM like the following:

```
div.mcoupdisplay
    div.mcoup //search result 1
            div.lcoup
        div.rcoup
            div.rcoupmeta
                a.rcoupedit
                a.rcoupdelete
        div.updcoup
        div.delcoup
    div.mcoup //search result 2
        div.lcoup
        div.rcoup
            div.rcoupmeta
                a.rcoupedit
                a.rcoupdelete
        div.updcoup
        div.delcoup
```

I currently hide all div.updcoup and div.delcoup and add slideToggle functionality with the following jQuery:

```
$('div.delcoup').hide();
$('a.rcoupdelete').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.delcoup').slideToggle(400);
    $('div.updcoup').slideUp(400);
    $('div.crecoup').slideUp(400);
    return false;
});

$('div.updcoup').hide();
$('a.rcoupedit').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.updcoup').slideToggle(400);
    $('div.delcoup').slideUp(400);
    $('div.crecoup').slideUp(400);
    return false;
});
```

Say div.updcoup is toggled in search result 1, then I toggle div.updcoup in search result 2.  How can I slideUp the visible div.updcoup search result 1 when I toggle the div.updcoup in search result 2?

Comment: A note: $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('div.delcoup') looks bad.  Try $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.delcoup'), as that depends less on your structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inspired by strager's comments.  His was not quite there, the final, working answer is below:

```
    $('div.delcoup').hide();
    $('a.rcoupdelete').click(function() {
        var thisDelcoup = $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.delcoup');
        $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.delcoup').slideToggle(400);
        $('div.delcoup').not(thisDelcoup).slideUp(400);
        $('div.updcoup').slideUp(400);
        $('div.crecoup').slideUp(400);
        return false;
    });

    $('div.updcoup').hide();
    $('a.rcoupedit').click(function() {
        var thisUpdcoup = $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.updcoup');
        $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.updcoup').slideToggle(400);
        $('div.delcoup').slideUp(400);
        $('div.updcoup').not(thisUpdcoup).slideUp(400);
        $('div.crecoup').slideUp(400);
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks for your help Strager!

Comment: I'm not sure how much different that is from my answer.  From what I see, instead of reusing thisDelcoup, you re-fetch the object.

Comment: When I used your code, it didn't work.  Mine does, that's how its different.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me, but reading just this:

> My question is what chain would work best to target all visible div.updcoup and div.delcoup

You want this:

```
$('div.updcoup:visible, div.delcoup:visible').slideUp(400);
```

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity.  I tried to be as clear as possible.

I want to add something like your answer to:
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll('div.delcoup').slideToggle(400);
So all *other*, visible, div.delcoup slideUp when $(this) is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove an item from the set?  If so, do this:

```
var thisDelcoup = $(this).closest('div.mcoup').find('div.delcoup').slideToggle(400);
$('div.delcoup').not(thisDelcoup).slideUp(400);
$('div.updcoup').slideUp(400);
$('div.crecoup').slideUp(400);
```

Comment: Your answer was so close! I'll the answer below.